# Using Drone-Kit to connect to Live Quad Copter

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit

I am tryingt to set a connection to a live quad copter using a the Drone-Kit api from the python command line. (I am using Python 2.7. I am also using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5)

> > > from dronekit import connect
> > >
> > > vehicle = connect('/dev/cu.usbserial-DJ00DA30', wait_ready=True)

I get a message:

> > > Link timeout, no heartbeat in last 5 seconds

In another 30 seconds, the command aborts. I know this is the correct device to use (cu.usbserial-DJ00DA30) because I am able to connect with it to the drone using APM Planner 2.0.

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I was able to solve this problem by making sure my pyserial was between 2.0 and 2.999 by using the following command:

```
sudo pip install "pySerial>=2.0,<=2.9999"
```

Seeing as this question was asked awhile ago, this may not be your problem, but perhaps a mismatch in pyserial and your dronekit version may be leading to the problem for you.

**END EDIT**

---

For anyone else coming across this post, here is the output PeterL is talking about after 30 seconds of no heartbeat found:

```
Connecting to vehicle on: /dev/cu.usbserial-DB00BWMM
>>> Link timeout, no heartbeat in last 5 seconds
>>> No heartbeat in 30 seconds, aborting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vehicle_state.py", line 23, in <module>
    vehicle = connect(args.connect, wait_ready=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 2354, in connect
    vehicle.initialize(rate=rate, heartbeat_timeout=heartbeat_timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 1815, in initialize
    raise APIException('Timeout in initializing connection.')
dronekit.APIException: Timeout in initializing connection.
```

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by inserting  "baud=57600" as the second argument in the connect statement.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Can't figure out what's wrong. I'm using raspberry pi zero and a usb->uart adaptor. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue yesterday and fixed it by installing the latest build from github. I'm on Windows 10 but in this case it should be irrelevant.